# in spite of everyone playing or in spite of playing

Tags: ellipsis

> 1.In spite of everyone playing well, we lost the game.
>
> 2.In spite of playing well, we lost the game.

Which is better? I prefer 2#. I think "everyone" and "we" are the same in this sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of your two sentences is correct.

"Everyone" is implied in the second sentence due to "we".

Your second sentence is shorter and would probably be preferred by a native speaker.  It could be further shortened to

> Despite playing well, we lost the game.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is right; the latter sentence is better than the former.

It seems that the phrase "in spite of" has been used as a conjunction in the former. If it's so, the sentence isn't grammatical. For example, you cannot say:

In spite of everyone played well, we lost the game.

However, you can use "the fact that" immediately after the phrase as follows:

In spite of the fact that everyone played well, we lost the game.

Alternatively, it's more appropriate to use "although" instead as follows:

Although everyone played well, we lost the game.